# Change image url using ternary operator when a condition is met

Tags: typescript, react-native

When the user shakes the phone I want to change an image, and let it stay rendered that way. With this I can change the image but it goes back once the condition is not fulfiled:

```
function Shaker(){
useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = accelerometer.subscribe(({ x, y, z }) =>
            setSensorData({ x, y, z })    
        );  
}, []);

const acceleration = Math.sqrt(sensorData.x * sensorData.x + sensorData.y * sensorData.y + sensorData.z * sensorData.z);
const imgchange = acceleration > 12 ? imgThatIwantToRenderAfterConditionAndStay.png : 'DefaultImg.png' ;
return (
        <View>
            <Image style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} source={{ uri: imgchange }} />
        </View>
}
```

When I created a boolean and passed it instead of `acceleration > 12` i got read only error:

```
const accelerationobtained = false;
if (acceleration > 12) { accelerationobtained = true; }
const ifimg = accelerationobtained ? imguri : 'https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/416-4167329_shot-glass.png' ;
```

I think my solution is dumb and I didnt expect it to work so I want to get educated on how should I handle such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are attempting to assign a new value to `accelerationobtained`, which is defined as a `const`:

> The `const` declaration creates a read-only reference to a value
> —[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description)

You can use `let accelerationobtained = false;`:

```
let accelerationobtained = false;
if (acceleration > 12) { accelerationobtained = true; }
const ifimg = accelerationobtained ? imguri : 'https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/416-4167329_shot-glass.png' ;
```

But is it really necessary though? If you're only using it once, you can inline the comparison of `acceleration` directly in the tenary statement:

```
const ifimg = acceleration > 12 ? imguri : 'https://www.nicepng.com/png/full/416-4167329_shot-glass.png' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that due to usage of hooks, the hook that carries the accelerator xyz values renders the page every x seconds. I couldnt find a solution to stop subscribing to the sensor, so I ignored it and went to solve the image problem, but I guess I cannot ignore it. When I used the sensor before in class in componentWillUnmount I used this.state.subscription.unsubscribe(); but I cant find a way to conditionally stop it in the function here.